# Filter all rows based on existance of element in array column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a spark dataframe similar to this:

| ... | Rules | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | [{"id": 1,...}, {"id": 2}] | ... |
| ... | [{"id": 5,...}] | ... |

`Rules` is an array column, where each element has the `id` field.

And I want to filter all rows which contain a rule with `id` < 3. Is it possible to do this **without UDFs**? My dataframe is very large and UDFs impair the perofrmace of my query.

Comment: I am never sure how much the performance is impaired - its is never quoted. Can you quantify this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `EXISTS` available on higher-order functions

```py
# Given dataset
+----------------------+
|Rules                 |
+----------------------+
|[{id -> 1}]           |
|[{id -> 1}, {id -> 2}]|
|[{id -> 5}]           |
+----------------------+

import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df_filtered_rules = df.where(f.expr("EXISTS(Rules, rule -> rule.id < 3)"))
df_filtered_rules.show(truncate=False)

+----------------------+
|Rules                 |
+----------------------+
|[{id -> 1}]           |
|[{id -> 1}, {id -> 2}]|
+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract map values from the array, find the max or(min depending on what you want) value in the array and check it is less than 3. That returns a boolean. You then can filter using the where clause.

```
+----------------------+
|Rules                 |
+----------------------+
|[{id -> 1}, {id -> 2}]|
|[{id -> 5}]           |
+----------------------+
```

If you want to filter only those rows with id less than 3, use;

```
df.where(expr("array_max(transform(Rules, x-> map_values(x)[0]))<3")).show(truncate=False)
```

If you want to filter  rows with any id less than 3, use;

```
df.where(expr("array_min(transform(Rules, x-> map_values(x)[0]))<3")).show(truncate=False)

+----------------------+
|Rules                 |
+----------------------+
|[{id -> 1}, {id -> 2}]|
+----------------------+
```